# cloud9 postgresql custom definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cloud9

with cloud9 and Rails, I want to access a database with these parameters :

database: mydatabase
username: myusername
password: mypassword

What is the process to achieve that ?

Comment: put those to database.yml and look if it is able to connect -))

Comment: No it is not. The problem comes probably from the setup of postgreslq

Answer (score 0):

In order to use postgres on C9, you have to set it up in the console

The detailed answer to using PG in C9 is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121251/cloud9-rails-postgresql-usage/44121268#44121268)