# Cloud9 + rails + Postgresql usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cloud9, c9.io

I can not set up a Rails app using Postgresql for development on Cloud9 (c9.io): the migration does not succeed.

Common error:

```
~/workspace (master) $ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud9 does not run PG by defalut. Below is the fast & easy way I use to use Postgresql on C9:

1.
Gemfile.rb:

```
gem 'pg'
```

2.
Database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: my_name
  password: my_pass
  host:     <%= ENV['IP'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_db_production
```

3. Paste the following code alltogether in the console:

`

```
sudo service postgresql start
sudo sudo -u postgres psql
CREATE USER my_name SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'my_pass';
\q
echo "export USERNAME=my_name"
echo "export PASSWORD=my_pass"
source
bundle
sudo sudo -u postgres psql
UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = FALSE WHERE datname = 'template1';
DROP DATABASE template1;
CREATE DATABASE template1 WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UNICODE';
UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template1';
\c template1
VACUUM FREEZE;
\q
bundle exec rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Done!
However after not using the app for some hours the db goes to sleep & you have to "switch" Postgres on manually by typing in the console:
`sudo service postgresql start`